# Read display string instead of macro in excel using python - openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, excel-2010, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl plugin to read excel sheet. I am using python 3.3.2 version

```
print((sheet.cell(row = 10, column = 2)).value)
```

I am trying to read B10 cell by above command. But it is returning excel cell's macro value. instead of what value is displayed in excel sheet.

Macro value it displays is

> =RTM_App!B15

(which is an another sheet called RTM_App and it's B15 cell. It contains string `"REQ_ID_1"`)

How can I get `"REQ_ID_1"` instead of macro `=RTM_App!B15`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data_only=True` when reading the workbook.